# How to Replace the Elements with Substrings with Previous Element of the Same List

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement, replace

I'm writing a Python script so that I can replace cells containing `not_assigned` and `uncultured` with the more informative classification in a simple tab-delimited file that looks like this:

```
1   d__Bacteria  p__Actinobacteriota    p__Actinobacteriota p__Actinobacteriota p__Actinobacteriota p__Actinobacteriota p__Actinobacteriota 0.738435964
2   d__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidota     c__Bacteroidia  o__Cytophagales    not_assigned    not_assigned    not_assigned    0.952907186
3   d__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidota     c__Bacteroidia  o__Flavobacteriales    not_assigned    not_assigned    not_assigned    0.866461874
4   d__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidota     c__Bacteroidia  o__Cytophagales    not_assigned    not_assigned    not_assigned    0.998657224
5   d__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidota     c__Bacteroidia not_assigned    not_assigned    not_assigned    not_assigned    1
6   d__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidota     c__Bacteroidia  o__Flavobacteriales    not_assigned    not_assigned    not_assigned    0.759620016
7   d__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidota     c__Bacteroidia not_assigned    not_assigned    not_assigned    not_assigned    0.863332682
8   d__Bacteria  p__Actinobacteriota     c__Acidimicrobiia   o__Microtrichales   f__Ilumatobacteraceae   g__uncultured   s__uncultured_bacterium    0.992474513
9   d__Bacteria  p__Actinobacteriota     c__Acidimicrobiia   o__Microtrichales   f__Microtrichaceae  g__uncultured  not_assigned    0.999376799
10  d__Bacteria  p__Actinobacteriota     c__Acidimicrobiia   o__Microtrichales   f__Microtrichaceae  g__uncultured   s__uncultured_actinobacterium  0.910988724
```

This file contains taxonomic information. `d__` is for `domain`, `p__` is for `phylum`, blah, blah, blah all the way up to `s__` for `species`. But some of these taxonomic levels are not identified so those levels contain words like `not_assigned` and `uncultured`. I want to find the first occurrence of these uninformative strings and replace them with the classification that is immediately previous to the `not_assigned` or `uncultured` and that is informative.

Take `line 2` for instance. I want to convert it from this:

```
2   d__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidota     c__Bacteroidia  o__Cytophagales    not_assigned    not_assigned    not_assigned    0.952907186
```

to this:

```
2   d__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidota     c__Bacteroidia  o__Cytophagales    o__Cytophagales o__Cytophagales o__Cytophagales 0.952907186
```

SO, I was able to write a code to replace the `not_assigned`s in my file, but I'm struggling with the `uncultured` containing cells because they vary. They can be `g__uncultured`, `s__uncultured_bacterium`, etc.

I'm hoping someone can please help me with the code that will replace the `uncultured` containing levels with the more informative level that comes before the first `uncultured` containing level. Below is my pseudocode and my current code.

Psuedocode:

```
for eachline in infile: #elements in each line are tab separated
    split eachline at tab:
    look at each element in the split list and find the first occurrence of an element containing the substring "not_assigned"
    if "not_assigned" substring found:
        previous that first "not_assigned" element and all subsequent elements with the previous element that is defined
        print the new line
    elif:
        do the same thing as the if block, but now with the substring "uncultured"
        print the new line
    else:
        just print the line
```

My current code that works for the `not_assigned` cells:

```
import sys
import re

asvtable = open(sys.argv[1], "r")

def replace_values(list_to_replace, item_to_replace, item_to_replace_with):
    return [item_to_replace_with if item == item_to_replace else item for item in list_to_replace]

for eachline in asvtable:
    eachline = eachline.strip()
    taxonomy = eachline.split("\t")
    if "not_assigned" in taxonomy:
        not_assigned_level_index = taxonomy.index("not_assigned")
        previous_level_name = taxonomy[:not_assigned_level_index][-1]
        new_taxonomy = replace_values(taxonomy, "not_assigned", previous_level_name)
        print(*new_taxonomy, sep='\t')
    else:
        print(*taxonomy, sep='\t')
```

Thank you very much! I hope my question make sense. Happy to clarify anything.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you simply want to replace 'not_assigned' and 'uncultured' values with the previous normal value in each row. I would reduce the complexity by using a for loop for each row. Then simply go over each value in a row and remember the last valid value in a variable. If either `not_assigned` or `uncultured` occurs it is replaced with the last valid value. Here would be the code:

```
asvtable = open('taxonomy.txt', "r")

for eachline in asvtable:
    taxonomy = eachline.strip().split("\t")

    last_valid_value = ''
    for i in range(len(taxonomy)):
        if 'not_assigned' in taxonomy[i] or 'uncultured' in taxonomy[i]:
            taxonomy[i] = last_valid_value
        else:
            last_valid_value = taxonomy[i]
    
    print(*taxonomy, sep='\t')
```

Output:

```
1   d__Bacteria p__Actinobacteriota p__Actinobacteriota p__Actinobacteriota p__Actinobacteriota p__Actinobacteriota p__Actinobacteriota 0.738435964
2   d__Bacteria p__Bacteroidota     c__Bacteroidia  o__Cytophagales o__Cytophagales o__Cytophagales o__Cytophagales 0.952907186
3   d__Bacteria p__Bacteroidota     c__Bacteroidia  o__Flavobacteriales o__Flavobacteriales o__Flavobacteriales o__Flavobacteriales 0.866461874
4   d__Bacteria p__Bacteroidota     c__Bacteroidia  o__Cytophagales o__Cytophagales o__Cytophagales o__Cytophagales 0.998657224
5   d__Bacteria p__Bacteroidota     c__Bacteroidia  c__Bacteroidia  c__Bacteroidia  c__Bacteroidia  c__Bacteroidia  1
6   d__Bacteria p__Bacteroidota     c__Bacteroidia  o__Flavobacteriales o__Flavobacteriales o__Flavobacteriales o__Flavobacteriales 0.759620016
7   d__Bacteria p__Bacteroidota     c__Bacteroidia  c__Bacteroidia  c__Bacteroidia  c__Bacteroidia  c__Bacteroidia  0.863332682
8   d__Bacteria p__Actinobacteriota     c__Acidimicrobiia   o__Microtrichales   f__Ilumatobacteraceae   f__Ilumatobacteraceae   f__Ilumatobacteraceae   0.992474513
9   d__Bacteria p__Actinobacteriota     c__Acidimicrobiia   o__Microtrichales   f__Microtrichaceae  f__Microtrichaceae  f__Microtrichaceae  0.999376799
10  d__Bacteria p__Actinobacteriota     c__Acidimicrobiia   o__Microtrichales   f__Microtrichaceae  f__Microtrichaceae  f__Microtrichaceae  0.910988724
```

If I understood it wrong it would help to add the outcome you expect for all ten line to your question.

Comment: THANK YOU @JANO! Yes, you understood my question absolutely correctly, and your code works beautifully! Can you please explain the `range(len(taxonomy))` part of the for loop? I started with a for loop but I couldn't get it to work as you did. Thank you again so very much!

Comment: Glad I could help! The `range(len(taxonomy))` statement is very useful when you want to loop over something. The variable `taxonomy` is a list of your values and `len(taxonomy)` gives you the length of your list. The `range(len(taxonomy))` gives you a list of numbers from `0` up to the length minus one. The loop now takes one number each loop iteration and assigns it to the variable `i`. This variable is very useful as it specifies each index of your list once in increasing order. With the index you can then read or write to that particular value in your list.

Comment: Not sure if it is understandable but it is for sure a concept to look into. It is used for almost any basic task in python. You can for example read (here)[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-list-in-python/] some methods to iterate over a list. Probably, there are better explanations.

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you so much for the explanation and the link. `range(len(X))` is definitely much better for looping over elements in a list. I kept using `list.index` but I will know better next time :-) Thank you, again @JANO!

Comment: No problem! Only wanted to add that `list.index` is still a useful statement to keep in mind and there are plenty of cases where you might want to use it. Also, if I answered your question you could consider marking my answer as accepted.